# How to get samples of Couchbase node stats from a range of time

Tags: monitoring, couchbase

I am trying to get samples of Couchbase node statistics like CPU utilization from a range of time.

I am using version 6.0, and I am using the API `curl -u a[admin]:[password] http://[localhost]:[port]/pools/default/buckets/default/nodes/[localhost]:[port]/stats` as detailed here https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/rest-api/rest-node-retrieve-stats.html . I see in v5.5 the *Bucket* statistics had a parameter `zoom` which lets me specify the interval of the samples, but the option `haveTStamp`seems to do nothing; Setting `.../stats?haveTStamp=1562341549265` for example has no effect on the range, I still get the results

```
{
  [...],
  {
    [...],
    "samplesCount":60,
    [...],
    "lastTStamp":[current epoch time],
    "interval":1000
}}
```

I expect there should be some parameter that lets me get the samples of the stats *starting* at a specific time, not just the last 60.